# Converting a Infix expression into a Postfix expression - invalid space insertion

Tags: java, parsing, spacing

I am making a converter that will take infix expressions and convert them into postfix expressions.

```
Example:
Infix: 2 * 3 - 10 / 4
Postfix: 2 3 * 10 4 / -
```

I have a the method completely coded but the postfix expression it returns is

```
2     3   *   1 0     4 / -
```

There are two problems with this: 1. The major problem is that their is a space between the 1 and 0, when they should be together (10). 2. There are a lot of extra spaces, the output should look like the example provided above.

I have done research on converting from infix to postfix, but I couldn't determine how to do more then single digit expression conversions.

Below is attached my postfixtoinfix class, the expression variable holds the infix indicated in the example above with perfect spacing.

```
import java.util.*;

public class InfixToPostfix
{
//Declare Instance Variables
private String expression;
private Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

//Constructor
public InfixToPostfix(String infixExpression)
{
        expression = infixExpression;
}//End of constructor

//Translate's the expression to postfix
public String translate()
{
    //Declare Method Variables
    String input = "";
    String output = "";
    char character = ' ';
    char nextCharacter = ' ';

    for(int x = 0; x < expression.length(); x++)
    {
        character = expression.charAt(x);

        if(isOperator(character))
        {
            while(!stack.empty() && precedence(stack.peek())>= precedence(character))
                output += stack.pop() + " ";
            stack.push(character);
        }   
        else if(character == '(')
        {
            stack.push(character);
        }
        else if(character == ')')
        {
            while(!stack.peek().equals('('))
                output += stack.pop() + " ";
            stack.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(character) && (x + 1) < expression.length() && Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(x+1)))
            {
                output += character;
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(character))
            {
                output += character + " ";
            }   
            else
            {
                output += character;
            }
        }
    }//End of for

    while(!stack.empty())
    {
        output += stack.pop() + " ";
    }

    return output;
}//End of translate method

//Check priority on characters
public static int precedence(char operator)
{
    if(operator == '+' || operator =='-')
        return 1;
    else if(operator == '*' || operator == '/')
        return 2;
    else
        return 0;
}//End of priority method

public boolean isOperator(char element)
{
    if(element == '*' || element == '-' || element == '/' || element == '+')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}//End of isOperator method

}//End of class
```

Comment: Please don't put "PLEASE HELP URGENT" in your question title.  Thanks.

Comment: Does anybody EVER talk about postfix without it being related to homework?

Comment: No, because if it wasn't homework I wouldn't be posting on here about it because I would have much more time to independently determine what's wrong.

Comment: Ha ha, you're under the mistaken impression that there are no due dates once you leave school.

Comment: On the bright side, it's a fun problem :-)

Comment: I know there are due dates after school.. What I intended to say is that im not doing this for fun, its actually been assigned to me.

Comment: Question Updated, It works now.
Is there a better way to code that 'else'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not seeing "10" as a single entity, but rather as two separate characters, '1', and '0'.  For anything that isn't an operator or parens you do `output += character + " ";` which is going to give you your `1 0` instead of the desired `10`.

Comment: Yeah i know what the problem is.
I just dont know a solution to it.

Comment: I guess the simple answer would be to look at where you are adding spaces.  For starters, the statement I pointed out is in the general else, which means if `character` is a space, then you are adding two spaces to output.

Comment: the general else is also applied to the any integer in the string, so the space addition is needed to separate it from the operators. 

Can I use something like if(character.isDigit()) add space and character else just add the character to output?

Comment: You might be able to use that, give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: in the else statement i tried

if(Character.isDigit(character) && Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(x+1)))
       {
        output += character;
       }
       else if(Character.isDigit(character))
       {
        output += character + " ";
       } 
       else
       {
        output += character;
       }


but i get StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, how would i work around that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem of converting an arbitrary arithmetic expression from its infix from (i.e. conventional for arithmetic expression) to a postfix form is not as simple as it might appear at first.

Arithmetic expressions represent a context free language, which can be recognised using a pushdown automation. As the result of such recognition a syntax tree or an AST (abstract syntax tree) could be constructed, which would be walked bottom-up in order to construct an postfix form.

A good practical book on this without too much of the theory is [Language Implementation Patterns](http://pragprog.com/book/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns), which I highly recommend.

Comment: I will surely read about that later.
currently, can you assist me in fixing my code in anyway?

Comment: Well... its not really about fixing it, it's more about getting it right from scratch.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to fix my current code.
I thought I was close to being done. 
I implemented the algorithm discussed in my class, so im sure its not completely incorrect.

Comment: The provided code won't be able to recognise a complete arithmetic expression language. Unless there are specific restrictions on how arithmetic expression can be constructed in your case (e.g. no nested parentheses) then a different solution should be developed (lexer for recognising lexems such as numbers, operations etc., and a parser to recognise a stream of lexems as a valid arithmetic expression)

Comment: My program only has to calculate + - * / and ( ).

Answer (score 1):

Like @digitaljoel said, you are recognizing individual characters as lexical tokens, instead of complete words as tokens.

Instead of reading a single character and then deciding what token (operator or operand) it is, you should be having the parser call a method to read the next complete token from the input. The token can then be returned as a string (containing one or more characters comprising the token), or as a class object (containing the text of the token, and some kind of token_type property).

Otherwise, your parser is limited to handling only single-character tokens.

Another benefit of using a separate lexical analyzer to read tokens is that you can handle whitespace in the lexer instead of in the parser.

Comment: @01es I understand that your solution is much more appropriate, but I am limited to using my current approach by lack of time and knowledge. 
Thank you for the information.

edit: question has been updated and double digits work now. I think my solution is quite inefficient, do you see anything i could change to make it better?