# Evaluate a N-variable Polynomial String

Tags: java, regex

I need to evaluate a n-variable polynomial string

`str = "-3a^5b^2c^3 + 12bc + xy + yz + xyz + 123";`.

Values of variables `input = "a=-2,b=-1,c=1,x=2,x=3,z=4";`

**What I've been able to do so far:**

1.) Break the `str` into individual terms like `"-3a^5b^2c^3"`, `"12bc"`, `"xy"`, `"yz"`, `"xyz"` as follows:

```
String[] terms = poly.split("-|\\+");
```

After Step1:

```
terms[] = {"-3a^5b^2c^3", "12abc", "xy", "yz", "xyz"};
```

2.) Extract values of variables from `input` as follows:

```
String[] parts = input.split(",");
String[] variables = new String[parts.length];

// Getting inputs
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
{
    String s = parts[i].substring(parts[i].indexOf('=')+1);
    variables[i] = s;
}
```

after step 2:

```
variables[] = {-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

I plan to evaluate individual terms of `terms[]` array and add/subtract them accordingly. But how am I supposed to break-up `"-3a^5b^2c^3"` into `3`, `a^5`, `b^2`, `c^2` ?

Manually doing it will consume too much lines of code and time and will make the code look complex.

I am new to Java and regex and having trouble finding its solution via regex.

Comment: Parsing mathematical expressions with a regular expression is hard, instead you should use a stack for this, Google evaluating mathematical expressions.

Comment: For one "-3a^5b^2c^3" this syntax has potential to be ambiguous.

consider the case of -3a^12b^2c^3

is this (-3a^12)(b^2)(c^2)
or (-3a^1)(2b^2)(c^2)
This is a bad example because of a^1, but you can see the issue nonetheless

Comment: Two questions : 1) Is the string always in the given format, or should it support any possible formula? 2) In that case, how do you know if your second term in the example is 1*2*a*b*c or 12*a*b*c? And if the first term is (-3a)^(5) or -3(a^5)(b^2) or -3(a^(5b)) etc..? If string "structure" is relatively fixed and operator precedence is very strict, then you can probably go on with string manipulations and regular expressions, otherwise you need a more sophisticated grammar and parser.

Comment: Also, before doing this, assuming that your input has 1 space before and after every + or -, you should do "poly.replaceAll("- ", "+ -");"

Comment: @Sniffer : Sir, at the first hand I tried googling it but was unable to find an acceptable solution. I know its too much to ask, but still, can you do it for me and pass on anything useful ?

@Cruncher : Once I am able to break terms of a string like `"12abc"` into `12`, `a`, `b`, `c` I will make the equivalent to `a^1`, `b^1`, `c^1`. Also I think I can handle the coefficient `"-3"`. My main task is to break-up `"-3a^5b^2c^3"` or `"12abc"` into individual terms. After that I can handle what remains.

Comment: @SimoneGianni The break up of terms should always be like `3, a^5, b^2, c^2` and not like cases you've mentioned.

@Cruncher I fail to see how it's gonna help :|

Comment: Check this [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10558343/439667). It contains everything you need to get going.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in three steps:

1. Identify the variables, numbers and operators and add them to a list. Using classes will probably make it easier to obtain precedence and associativity later.
2. Then reorder the expression with the Shunting-yard algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm.
3. Finally the expression will be in Reverse Polish notation and it's fairly easy to evaluate the expression http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_Notation.

Since you asked for help about the regex, I completed the first step. I just added a string for each element to keep the code and result simple. It should be obvious how to alter the code to add class objects to the list instead of strings.

```
from re import match

def toList(expr):
    print '\n> toList(%s)' % expr
    result = []
    index = 0
    expectsOp = False
    while index < len(expr):
        if expectsOp:
            next = match(r'(?P<Skip> +)|(?P<Operator>[-+*/^])', expr[index:])
            if next:
                if next.group('Operator'):
                    result.append('Op:%s' % next.group('Operator'))
                    index += len(next.group('Operator'))
                elif next.group('Skip'):
                    index += len(next.group('Skip'))
                    continue
            else:
                result.append('Op:*')
            expectsOp = False
        else:
            next = match(r'(?P<Skip> +)|(?P<Number>[-+]?\d+)|(?P<Variable>[A-Za-z])', expr[index:])
            if next:
                if next.group('Number'):
                    result.append('Num:%s' % next.group('Number'))
                    index += len(next.group('Number'))
                elif next.group('Variable'):
                    result.append('Var:%s' % next.group('Variable'))
                    index += len(next.group('Variable'))
                elif next.group('Skip'):
                    index += len(next.group('Skip'))
                    continue
            else:
                return 'Error: Expected variable or number, but found "...%s"' % expr[index:]
            expectsOp = True

    return result

print toList("-3a^5b^2c^3 + 12bc + xy + yz + xyz + 123")
```

Produces the result:

```
> toList(-3a^5b^2c^3 + 12bc + xy + yz + xyz + 123)
['Num:-3', 'Op:*', 'Var:a', 'Op:^', 'Num:5', 'Op:*', 'Var:b', 'Op:^', 'Num:2', 'Op:*', 'Var:c', 'Op:^', 'Num:3', 'Op:+', 'Num:12', 'Op:*', 'Var:b', 'Op:*', 'Var:c', 'Op:+', 'Var:x', 'Op:*', 'Var:y', 'Op:+', 'Var:y', 'Op:*', 'Var:z', 'Op:+', 'Var:x', 'Op:*', 'Var:y', 'Op:*', 'Var:z', 'Op:+', 'Num:123']
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I just noticed you use Java and not Python. The principle should be the same however so just think of it like pseudo code.